# Issue in http client authentication header and posting multipart form data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dotnet-httpclient

I am developing a windows phone 8 app. Now i have to post an image selected from my gallery to the web api. This api is password protected and therefore username and password in authentication header of http client library need to be passed on. Secondly data in the form of image, aboutme, and other properties are to be posted at api. But there is an issue i dont know some how its crashing . I have given text api in this code snippet if actual needed then u can ask me. But need to know wat i am doing wrong in passing http client header with form data.
My code snippet is below given:

```
 async   void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
          //  MessageBox.Show(e.ChosenPhoto.Length.ToString());

            //Code to display the photo on the page in an image control named myImage.


            photoStream = new MemoryStream();


            e.ChosenPhoto.CopyTo(photoStream);


            fileName = e.OriginalFileName;


            MessageBox.Show(fileName);


            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

            int a = bmp.PixelHeight;
            int b = bmp.PixelWidth;

            ApplicationSettingHelper.AddOrUpdateValue("profilepicture", e.OriginalFileName);
            ApplicationSettingHelper.Save();


                string User_id = "221296";
                string About_me = AboutMeText.Text;
                string Country = "Dubai";
                string Session_token = "54143870560e6136764dc9.77573702";                              
                byte[] Imagedata = bitmapConverter(bmp);


                UploadFile(User_id, About_me, Country, Session_token, photoStream);

}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
  private async void UploadFile(string user_id,string about_me,string country,string session_token,MemoryStream photoStream)
    {
        try
        {
            // Make sure there is a picture selected
            if (photoStream != null)
            {
                 const string uri = "http://api.etc";
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                { 
                    var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("prototype:prototype");
                    var header = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                               "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = header;




                    MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                    content.Add(new StreamContent(photoStream), "profile_image");
                    content.Add(new StringContent(user_id), "user_id");
                    content.Add(new StringContent(about_me), "about_me");
                    content.Add(new StringContent(country), "country");
                    content.Add(new StringContent(session_token), "session_token");


                    // var result = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

                    await client.PostAsync(uri, content)
                    .ContinueWith((postTask) =>
                    {
                        postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    });



                }



        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var message = ex.Message + ex.StackTrace.ToString();
            var test = message;

        }
    }
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: i have debugged it. it says unknown error and always fall into catch block in upload method . If needed u can simply run it , i can provide u with my web api. But issue is either in authenticating api before getting permission to post data

Comment: post your stacktrace

Comment: here's my stack trace:                                    at System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Position(Int64 value)
   at TheEntertainer.EditProfilePage.<UploadFile>d__4.MoveNext()

Comment: Where does it exactly goes to catch?

Comment: as soon as the call is made ... at line client.postAsync(); if u require i can send or mail u my complete snippet. bcz it has taken my 2 days and i still cant figure out :D

Comment: send it to amitghosh.in@live.com

Comment: hey just mailed u .. waiting for ur response